# Passing Any as a function parameter

Tags: scala

This code :

```
  val l1: List[String] = List("test")             //> l1  : List[String] = List(test)
    val l2: String = "test"                   //> l2  : String = test

  def printVal(s: Any) = {
    println(s)
  }                                               //> printVal: (s: Any)Unit

  printVal(l1)                                    //> List(test)
  printVal(l2)                                    //> test
```

compiles and run's as expected.

If I attempt something similar like :

```
  val arr: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array((("1", "2"), 4.5))
                                                  //> arr  : Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array(((1,2),4.5))
  def printCol(arr: Array[Any]) = {
    arr.foreach { case (e, i) => println(e + "," + i) }
  }                                               //> printCol: (arr: Array[Any])Unit

  printCol(arr)
```

Then I receive compile time error :

```
type mismatch; found : Array[((String, String), Double)] required: Array[Any] Note: ((String, String), Double) <: 
 any, but class array is invariant in type t. you may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <
```

As `[Tuple2,Double]` is not a subType of `Any`

Can the function `printCol` be rewritten so that it accepts Any type as its parameter and prints the collection values ?

Something like ? :

```
  def printCol(arr: Array[((Any, Any) , (Any))]) = {
        arr.foreach { case (e, i) => println(e + "," + i) }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def printCol[A,B,C](arr: Array[((A,B),C)]) = {
  arr.foreach { case (e, i) => println(e + "," + i) }
}
```

Then feel free to add constraints depending on your use case, you could do that:

```
def printCol[A,B](arr: Array[((A,A),B)]) = {
  arr.foreach { case (e, i) => println(e + "," + i) }
}
```

To enforce that both elements of the inner tuple have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in Java `String[]` cannot be directly assigned to a variable of type `Object[]`. Scala has to obey this rule.

You can very easily rewrite your code:

```
val arr: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array((("1", "2"), 4.5))           
//|arr: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array(((1,2),4.5))

def printCol(arr: Array[_]) = {                                              
  arr.foreach { case (e, i) => println(e + "," + i) }                             
}                                                                               
//|printCol: printCol[](val arr: Array[_]) => Unit

printCol(arr)                                                                   
//|(1,2),4.5
//|res0: Unit = ()
```

When you changed `printCol` so it accepts `Array[Any]` or `Array[AnyRef]` you would have to provide precisely that type. So you are better of with an unspecified generic.